# Fluent NHibernate data removed after schema update

Tags: database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I'm using Fluent NHibernate to work with my database.

When running the following code some things work. 
One function updates the tables structure, which also works, but my data is gone.

```
ISessionFactory result = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Page>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? The tables have to be updated, but the data must not be removed.

On the wiki from fluent NH I can't find more info about `ExposeConfiguration`.

Answer (score 16):

`SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))` is what's doing it.  I haven't used Fluent, but based on one of my projects I just looked at, I think it should be something like `SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true,true)`

Edit:  Since this answer still seems to be helping people, here's a longer winded explaination.

The main difference here is the object that we're creating.  The `SchemaExport` instance generates DDL to create the database.  The `Create` method generates the script, and the second parameter tells it whether or not to run that script against the database.  `Create` calls `Execute`, passing additional parameters, including one that says "don't just drop the table, drop it and re-create it".  There is no option in this class to not drop the tables first.

The `SchemaUpdate` instance is a much more complicated beast (internally), because it looks at the existing tables and generates a delta between the current tables and those specified in the configuration (I can't find a reference for this, and I didn't look at the code, I just know it works).  In both cases though, the parameters are basically the same.  The first one is "output ddl to console" and the second is "actually run the thing against the database".